# Exclude Articles From Blog Home Page if Article Contains Specific Tag?

Tags: shopify, liquid

On our blog homepage I'd like to exclude certain articles if the article contains a specific tag. For example, if I visit https://example.com/blogs/sample-blog I'd like to exclude all posts that include the tag "example-tag".

I'd still like to show the articles if I visit the tagged url such as https://example.com/blogs/sample-blog/tagged/example-tag.

I've tried variations of the following code in our blog template but can't get anything to work.

```
{% unless article.tags contains 'example-tag' %}
    Code Here
{% endunless %}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a boolean variable:

```
{% assign realtedTag = false %}  

{% if article.tags contains 'example-tag' %} 
{% assign realtedTag = true %} 
{% endif%}

{% if realtedTag == false %} 
 Show your article 
{% endif%}
```